# Unable to edit individual objects made by the Array modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I created an object and multiplied it with an **Array Modifier**, but the problem is:

X - original object

X X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ... Xn - final object (array size = n)

I'm only able to edit **X**, and if I do, all the others X*n* will change as well.
How can I reverse this? If i want to edit only, for example, X4 face or vertex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is intended functionality - it is supposed to work like that. An array modifier makes an array of a single object so if you change that object, all the array is supposed to change as well.

You can apply the modifier and edit the generated geometry as you wish or if you wish to have multiple objects you can duplicate them with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. If you perform the transforms with the duplicate operator(move or scale or rotate the object right after pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> before confirming it) you can then repeat the action with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to make an array quickly.

I assume that by 'edit' you mean going into edit mode and changing the geometry. You can still influence, deform or even change the geometry of parts of the object that is generated with the Array modifier by using other modifiers without editing the actual original object:

[image]

Comment: But there is anyway to do it the way i did?

Comment: No. You need to do it the way it is done, and cannot do something else and then order the result to be as you wish, I am afraid. The functionality is the way it is intended to be. What you want to do is simply done another way.

Answer (score 1):

A Particle System may suit you..

- Create a Group <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> of variants of your panel, ensuring the geometry of each item is aligned with respect to its origin.
- Assign a Particle System to a guide for the collection of panels. (Here, the guide is a mesh with six vertices on an edge)
- Set the Render to Group, as shown, with 'Pick Random' to randomly distribute variants.

You can get more control of the order in which the panels appear by using the 'Count' mechanism in the same panel, which allows you to fix a cycle of choices from the group repeating internally if wished.

A Particle system also allows you to add small random variations to the relative locations and rotations of each instance, for added realism.

You can edit any of the panel variants, and the changes will be reflected in the collection.

A strip of faces, or an array of another object, may be a better guide, depending on the sort of control you want.

[image]

You can make the panels real instances by pressing 'Convert' in the guide's Particle System modifier.